# I have designed a sorting algorithm for a char linked list in c++ but it doesn't work

Tags: c++, linked-list

I had tried to build a sorting algorithm for my linked list program which would sort my linked list into alphabetical order by checking the **first** element with the second, third etc and then the second would be compared with rest and so on, but it isn't working. What's wrong?

```
   struct list* sort_list(struct list *head)
    {
    struct list *current= (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    struct list *previous=(struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    struct list *point=(struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));

    char tmp[30];

      current = head;
      previous = NULL;
      point=head;

        while(point!=NULL)
        {
           while (current != NULL) 
           {
               if(strcmp(point->data,current->data)>0)
               {
                  swap(head,point,current);
               }

               previous = current;

               current = current->next;
            }

          point=point->next;
      }

      return head;

}




    void swap(struct list *head,struct list *first,struct list *second) {

    char *tempValue;
    tempValue = first->data;
    first->data = second->data;
    second->data = tempValue;
}
```

List Structure:

```
struct list
{
char *data;
struct list *next;
}list;
```

Comment: can you provide the code for list structure also?

Comment: This really isn't `C++`, some dead giveaways of that fact are the raw pointers, `struct` littered about, `strcmp` and `malloc`.  In C++, you would do this with `std::list`, `std::string` and `std::sort`.

Comment: One problem is that you allocate space for `current` to point at and then leak it by assigning `current = head;`. Ditto for `previous` and `point`. That bodes ill.

Comment: You have memory leaks with the unneeded malloc. 'tmp' and 'previous' are not used, swap should take only 2 args (std::swap(point->data,current->data)).

Comment: @Chad Sorry. I am not really good at C++ so that could be the reason.

Comment: If the list is of significant size, this bubble sort (in addition to having memory leaks) will take forever!

Comment: Oh! What can i possibly do to resolve that an yet not make it complex?

Comment: The easiest solution is to use the `std::string` version I put below.  If you absolutely must use a linked-list, then the `std::list` version below would do it.  If this is a homework assignment requiring you to write your own linked-list, then I would first start by fixing your memory leaks.

Comment: Oh, and why are you passing the head pointer to your swap function, yet never using it?  If you don't need it, don't declare your swap function with it as an argument.

Comment: @ZacHowland Yeah it is an assignment actually. :)
And thanks for your help. I'm working on it now.

Comment: Since your `swap` does not use the first argument, `head`, there is really no point in passing it, is there?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
while (point != NULL) {
    while (current != NULL) {
```

By

```
while (point != NULL) {
    current = point->next;
    while (current != NULL) {
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace all of the listed code with:

```
std::list<char> myList;

// fill my list with a bunch of characters

myList.sort();
```

or a slightly more memory efficient version:

```
std::string myList;

// fill my list with a bunch of characters

std::sort(myList.begin(), myList.end());
```

Comment: `std::sort` doesn't work with lists. You need the member function for that.

Comment: Oops ... typing too fast.  Corrected.

Comment: There is a doubt. Actually, as you have mentioned in the comment that I need to fill in some characters i.e., for sorting. I already have words in the list which i had read from a file(part of the assignment). How can i put that into use?

Comment: If you need to sort words, then you would change it to a list of strings:  `std::list<std::string> myList; /* fill in strings */ myList.sort();`  (NOTE:  that will do a case-sensitive sort; if you need a case insensitive sort, you'll need to write a comparison function and pass that into your sort method call)